# Network Adapter & System Time Problems on my ROG GL552VX Laptop

Tags: networking, dual-boot, 16.04, system

Every time I first boot my new laptop into 16.04 LTS, and then reboot into Windows 7 (needed for my work), I get those 2 problems :

1) System Time gets a 2 hours difference in Windows (5.14pm under 16.04 LTS and then 03.14pm under Win 7) ===> Only Solution : Set Manually the time ... Not nice but working :(

2) Network Adapter gets recognized and its fixed IP but nothing works, even a simple ping to another LAN device ===> Only Solution : Reboot into Windows 7

If anyone has an idea for one or both problems, feel free to send me a message ..

Albert E.

Answer (score 0):

Albert,

This happens because Windows doesn't do GMT offset timing by default.  To fix this, open Registry editor.

Navigate to

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation**

Right click anywhere in the right pane and hit New > **DWORD (32-bit) Value**. Name it **RealTimeIsUniversal**, then double click on it and give it a value of **1**.

As for the networking.  I'm not sure off the top of my head, can you send a dump of ifconfig?

Thanks, 
PC

Comment: Now, I get a 2 hours difference ... But "ahead" of the real time :-( What the hell is wrong in this crappy Windows Time Management ... ?

Comment: You do have to boot back into Linux, then back into windows for this to take effect, as Linux will  set the BIOS clock again, then Windows will read it as GMT offset after.  Then hopefully things should stay in sync?